# What do you call a person who is always noisy on the Internet?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, pejorative-language, offensive-language, epithet-requests

*Noisy*, in a way, that he always post on Facebook or Twitter anything he did like it is his diary, always commenting other people's posts, retweets every minute or hour, etc. An attention whore or something. Is there a specific word for this kind of personality?

By the way, I didn't mean *nosy or nosey*.

Comment: Attention whore or validation seeker is what comes to mind for me as well. I'd like to hear a more 'formal' word, though.

Comment: Does it have to be the internet?

Comment: I don't know of a single word, but "overactive poster" seems like nice epithet-noun combo for it (and it contrasts with the standard "active poster"). "Excessive poster" also works. There's also the word "nethead," but this doesn't have a connotation involving being noisy, just that someone is enthusiastic about the internet.

Comment: I'd call him "unfriended".

Comment: @Mari-LouA No, I think he means _noisy_. It's not about having your nose in other people's business, but about constantly writing stuff—the Internet equivalent to a real chatterbox who never stops talking. That kind of noisy,

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet   I've never heard of anyone being "noisy" on the Internet, but if words written in CAPS means people are shouting, I guess people can make virtual "noise". It's that sometimes I have come across learners who write *noise* instead of *nose*, I thought this might be another case in question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA yep you got my point. I didn't mean nosey.

Comment: I think I was the only one who thought there might be a misunderstanding :)

Comment: i like this question because it sounds like the setup to a joke. "I don't know, what *DO* you call a person who is two noisy on the internet? :D"

Comment: @Mitch yes because it would be easy if my OP is referring to people who are, literally, noisy.

Comment: I would call him: annoying person.

Comment: Annoying is too general.  I am finding an exact word, if there is.

Comment: @kenorb, haha literally, annoying indeed, but that's not the word I am looking for

Comment: Typical Facebook or Twitter user? You can avoid this by avoiding antisocial media.

Answer (score 24):

Potentially an *oversharer*, but the word often means sharing details about your life that are either embarrassing to you or discomfiting to others.

[***overshare***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/over-sharer) -

> to disclose too much (personal information) or too many (details) about oneself

It does not, alas, mean that guy that just has to share his 2 cents about everything.

Comment: I think this is the closest answer on my OP. Attention whore, social media addict, and garrulous can be considered too.

Comment: Doesn't this word sound too technically or too "modern"?

Comment: I think this word does the best of any answers I've seen so far without seeming archaic or having unwanted connotations. Being "too modern" is an advantage IMO when the intended meaning is a modern phenomenon. As an alternative, use my answer, *exhibitionist*.

Comment: The OP didn't ask about (or even mention) connotation, therefore you are wrong to argue that other answers are incorrect *because of their connotation*.

Comment: I agree on to that @L0j1k.

Comment: Swords into ploughshares?

Answer (score 21):

An "**attention whore**" is a widely-used term for this, someone who must be the center of attention, and does things and causes situations which puts them in the center of attention, into the spotlight. Of course, it is not something you would say to another person, as it is considered an insult. It conveys the same meaning regardless of whether or not the person is online, and so in this way if you are seeking an exclusively-online term -- or a term which is not insulting -- this may not fit your circumstances.

Comment: Some people, especially those with some kind of fundamental social disorder (e.g. the classic *Aspergers* cases), are often unaware of the intensity of their sharing. Instead of wanting to be the centre of attention, they're oblivious to the fact that the conversation isn't necessarily about them and that sometimes it's better to keep quiet. How do you distinguish between actively seeking attention and just being socially inept?

Comment: Me personally? I take each person's behavior into consideration. It is after all a *social* network, and so a blanket answer here would be less than ideal. But to answer your question more broadly: If the door is red, the door is red, regardless of how it got that way.

Comment: This term also conveys an assumed negative attitude towards sex workers (and perhaps towards female sexuality in general), which makes it inappropriate in many contexts and arguably preferable not to use at all.

Comment: As linguists, we do not prescribe language, we describe it.

Comment: @L0j1k: I don't see how that response is relevant. Coverage of connotations and attitudes implied by word choice are relevant to someone seeking a word to use in speech or writing, and most importantly, mentioning them *is descriptive*, not prescriptive.

Comment: To elaborate, this word choice might be perfectly fine to have a character in a book or screenplay use, but would easily get your speaking invitation revoked if you used it in slides for a conference except in very specific situations.

Comment: You must not have read my entire answer. Specifically, "Of course, it is not something you would say to another person, as it is considered an insult."

Comment: @L0j1k: Being an insult to the person it's applied to has nothing to do with the reasons why it would get you kicked out of a well-managed conference.

Answer (score 19):

He may have

**[logorrhea](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/logorrhea?s=t)**

> 1. pathologically incoherent, repetitious speech.
> 2. **incessant or compulsive talkativeness; wearisome volubility.**

And if the above is tempting but not quite a perfect fit, I'd like to humbly submit the not-yet-a-real-word "blogorrhea" for your specific case.

Unfortunately of course this is a name for his condition, not for him himself.

Answer (score 14):

You could use **social media addict**.

It's doesn't fit the description exactly, as a social media addict doesn't necessarily overshare publicly (eg, you can have social media addicts who are just messaging their friends, or browsing instagram).

eg.

> Bob is a bit of a social media addict - he's liked twenty pictures and commented on ten of them in the last hour alone.

Comment: ..and they were all his own..

Comment: @user3306356 forever alone. haha

Answer (score 11):

There is a punchline to a Penny Arcade comic that I think sums this up very well: A [Twitter Shitter](http://www.penny-arcade.com/comic/2008/04/23)

Answer (score 6):

> [**garrulous**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/garrulous) *- excessively talkative, especially on trivial matters*

is usually applied in *spoken* contexts, rather than to "non-vocal" online postings. But given OP has already used ***noisy*** himself, I think it's appropriate.

Comment: Seems to me that OP is specifically looking for something like "noisy" *without* the connotation of it being spoken.

Comment: @MatthewRead Exactly. I have already explained in my OP my definition of  "noisy".

Comment: @Matthew: Until relatively recently, one of the big differences between spoken and written "conversations" was that only the former could normally take place in anything approximating real-time, but online ***chat*** facilities have changed all that. So it's now perfectly reasonable to extend words like ***talk, conversation*** and [***garrulous online***](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=-YOvVbuYKej88wfZobywAw&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22garrulous+online%22) to contexts such as a [***garrulous blog***](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=v4OvVcmoDOj88wfZobywAw&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22garrulous+blog%22).

Answer (score 6):

How about an **E**-ttention whore?

Comment: And the closely related *i-Diot*?

Comment: @WernerCD e-xactly. Haha

Comment: I think you win.

Answer (score 6):

[exhibitionist](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/exhibitionist)

> A person who behaves in an extravagant way in order to attract attention

If desired you could attach an adjective [phrase] like "online", "social media", "digital", etc. to be more specific, but I don't think it's needed.

Answer (score 4):

Although not particularly Internet related, I'd call them a

[***chatterbox***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/chatterbox)

> A person who likes to chatter.

[***chatter***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/chatter)

> Talk informally about unimportant matters.

Comment: I think this is vaguely more internet related than you might think due to [I.R.C.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/irc) I think [chatty](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/chatty) is also applicable, albeit not necessarily as derogatory.

Answer (score 3):

**Lifelogging enthusiast**. Was a thing before twitter/facefook, albeit non-public.

Answer (score 1):

All the actions of person revolve around seeking attention, so

attention seeker

Comment: I presume attention seeker and attention whore are synonymous.

Answer (score 1):

**vain**, adjective –[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vain)

> 4 : having or showing undue or excessive pride in one's appearance or achievements

Anyone who feels the need to update their status for the world at large is vain. They probably also think [this song](https://www.google.com/search?q=you%27re%20so%20vain&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) is about them.

Comment: One up for the song reference -- though it's stuck in my head now...

Answer (score 0):

A ***very* active** (or *overactive*) user is what I would call them.
<del>A troll would be someone who posts comments to things ad nauseam and out of spite.</del>

Comment: I don't think troll is a good word here. Trolls may sometimes be attention seekers, but often being a troll is associated with doing something that seems earnest, but is actually not (often to provoke infuriating reactions, etc.)

There are trolls who post very little and whom are rather quiet online, for example.

Comment: @Othya This does not say that troll is the correct word, but rather that the correct word is not troll because "a troll would be someone who post[s] comments ... out of spite."

Comment: @Blubberguy22 I disagree with your reading, but even if so -- why mention it?  There is a virtually limitless number of words that are not correct here, and the OP does not mention "troll".

Comment: @MatthewRead I agree with you there, "troll" is indeed irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

How about a loudmouth? While granting that, being the internet, we can't actually hear them. At least not yet, web3?

[Cambridge: loudmouth](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/loudmouth)

Answer (score -1):

Itchy-fingers sounds appropriate 
Just like some of the above suggestions this is also not formal English as such